# Python: Рекурсивный поиск связанных данных в БД.

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Всем привет. Есть следующая база данных. Стоит задача, рекурсивно искать все поля id, у которых parent_id одинаковый и удалять их. Ниже код, который по идее должен это реализовывать, но что-то все это чудо не заводится. Ниже предоставил свой код, логи и скрин БД. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Логи

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context

    context)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 507, in do_execute

    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "WHERE"

LINE 1: UPDATE kit.layout SET  WHERE kit.layout.id = 183

                               ^





The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/websocket.py", line 498, in _run_callback

    result = callback(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/rm-interface-platform-transmitter-server/controller/api/v1/ws/handlers/connector.py", line 33, in on_message

    connection=self

  File "/opt/rm-interface-platform-transmitter-server/controller/helpers/ws/messaging/consumer.py", line 238, in get_message

    executor(message['body'], connection)

  File "/opt/rm-interface-platform-transmitter-server/controller/api/v1/ws/helpers/builder/builder.py", line 167, in update_layout

    result = doc.update_layout(message_body).result()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 296, in wrapper

    result = func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/types.py", line 248, in wrapped

    coro = func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/opt/rm-interface-platform-transmitter-server/controller/api/v1/ws/helpers/share/data_table/service.py", line 341, in update_layout

    ).update(message_body)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 3416, in update

    update_op.exec_()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1326, in exec_

    self._do_exec()

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1493, in _do_exec

    self._execute_stmt(update_stmt)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1333, in _execute_stmt

    mapper=self.mapper)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1176, in execute

    bind, close_with_result=True).execute(clause, params or {})

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 948, in execute

    return meth(self, multiparams, params)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 269, in _execute_on_connection

    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1060, in _execute_clauseelement

    compiled_sql, distilled_params

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1200, in _execute_context

    context)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1413, in _handle_dbapi_exception

    exc_info

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause

    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 186, in reraise

    raise value.with_traceback(tb)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1193, in _execute_context

    context)

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 507, in do_execute

    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "WHERE"

LINE 1: UPDATE kit.layout SET  WHERE kit.layout.id = 183

                               ^

 [SQL: 'UPDATE kit.layout SET  WHERE kit.layout.id = %(id_1)s'] [parameters: {'id_1': 183}] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Сам код.

```
@gen.coroutine
def delete_layout(self, layout_id):
    def get_child_ids(_layout_id):
        layout_ids = [_layout_id]
        if _layout_id == layout_ids:
            return layout_id
        else:
            return self.db_session.query(
                Layout.parent_id
            ).filter(
                Layout.parent_id == layout_id
            ).all

    child_ids = get_child_ids(layout_id)
    for child_id in child_ids:
        self.db_session.query(
            Layout
        ).filter(
            Layout.id == child_id
        ).delete()
    self.db_session.commit()

    return {
        'deleted_layout_ids': child_ids
    }
```

Структура БД.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите удалить повторы по атрибуту - то можно следующим образом.

Получаете списком кортежей строки таблицы (fetch) и далее работаете с ними. Пробегитесь по таблице и добавьте в список уникальные ключи всех строк-дублей:

```
# поля key, id, name - найдём у кого повторяются id и удалим все кроме первого
rows = [(1, 1,'a'), (2, 2, 'b'), (3, 2,'c'), (4, 3, 'd')]
id_list = []
id_delete = []
for row in rows:
    if row[1] not in id_list:
        id_list.append(row[1])
    else:
        id_delete.append(row[0])

# Далее берём лист id_delete - в нём хранятся уникальные 
# идентификаторы строк, которые необходимо удалить
```